# Convergence of a series through ratio test

Tags: analysis

Does the ratio test show the convergence of a sequence or convergence of a series from 1 to infinity or both ? We used ratio test for determining the convergence of a sequence but im not sure if it applies to an infinite series as well

Answer (score 0):

It shows the convergence of the series. But by the divergence test, any convergent series has terms approaching zero, so actually you get both.